# JQuery Registration Form onclick popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to make a Javascript JQuery registration form pop-up on link click.

So I have this button:

```
<a href="#" class="cta">REGISTER NOW</a>
```

And I`m trying to make it pop-up a small simple html registration form that I can store in a hidden registration DIV. Example:

```
<div name="reg" style="visibility:hidden;">reg form</div>
```

I just need the simple registration form (Only full name and email) to pop-up (centered and mobile responsive) when that button is linked.

Can I get any help in doing this? Thank you.
I have tried with jquery dialog and almost everything found on Google, but it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Bootstrap modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)?

Comment: Not really.....

Comment: It's the perfect solution for your problem. If you have the time you should definitely check out bootstrap and it's various components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by **Mihailo**, you could use Bootstrap Modals to make it responsive (mobile, tablet and PC).

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-sm" role="button" class="">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Registration</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="reg-form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-name" class="control-label">Full Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email Address:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the thing, there is a modal template with header section, body section and footer section.

> div class="modal **fade** bs-example-modal-sm"

If you remove **fade**, then the modal will not animate.

More information regarding bootstrap modals is [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Also, Please find the corresponding JsFiddle below:
https://jsfiddle.net/Manoj85/7egtc2ne/5/

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a class or id on you register div instead, but you can show the form like this:

```
$('.cta').click(function() {
    $('div[name="reg"]').css('visibility', 'visible');
})
```

Once you give your div a proper class/id, you can replace `div[name="reg"]` with `.class` or `#id`. Additionally, jQuery has several built-in functions for hiding and showing elements. To use these, you'll want to change `visibility:hidden;` with `display:none;`. Then, in the code I presented above, replace `.css(...)` with one of the following:

- `.show()` is an immediate effect, and is the same as changing the display property to `block`. To remove again, use `.hide()`.
- `.fadeIn()`, as the name suggests, is more of a gradual fading effect. Opposite of `.fadeOut()`.
- `slideDown()` is similar to an "accordian" effect, where the element starts at 0 height and "grows". Opposite of `.slideUp()`.

You can also use `.toggle()`, `.fadeToggle()`, or `slideToggle()`, respectively to alternate between showing and hiding the elements.

I've created [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/zj0gtt6p/) to demonstrate these effects.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have managed to do this by Bootstrap Modal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a div called register, which you need to add, it will be like this:

```
 <script> 
    $(".cta").click(function() {
        $("#register").css("hidden", false)
     })
 </script>
```